Change the Subject header of an email in postfix based on the To header
After reading thru the postfix header_check man page and reading the internet I came up with this PCRE to delete the Subject header and then add the Subject back with the data I need. But the second line does not seem to delete the Subject header, it adds the second Subject header which cause an error. Surly I'm missing something simple here?
if /^To: .*fax\.faxserverdomain\.com$/i
/^Subject:.*$/i IGNORE
/^To: (fax=|)(\d+)@.*fax\.faxserverdomain\.com$/i PREPEND Subject: [sendfax] $2
endif

